# Serialization using XDR RFC 4506

Tags: r, xdr

I need to serialize some R objects into an XDR format that complies to RFC 4506 standards. I know about `serialize`:

```
serialize("Hello world", NULL) # xdr = TRUE
 # [1] 58 0a 00 00 00 02 00 03 04 02 00 02 03 00 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 01 00 04 00 09 00 00 00 0b 48 65 6c 6c 6f 20 77 6f 72 6c 64
```

[With a bit of googling](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html#Serialization-Formats), it seems that R formats to RFC 1832, not RFC 4506. I can't seem to find any libraries that specifically handle XDR serialization to different formats.

Can anyone point me to a good library, or failing that some good resources for doing this by hand? I haven't had any experience with XDR before today, and I am already aware of [this](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4506), which is a bit dry.

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_Data_Representation) RFC 4506 does not make any technical changes to RFC 1832. Have you encountered any problems with the format produced by R?

Comment: I haven't dived in properly yet, as I don't want to go down a rabbit hole implementing something manually if it isn't required. However, I've got a base64 encoded string which when decoded should give me an XDR serialized series of values, but when I pass this to `unserialize()` the format is unrecognised by R. I think I read that `serialize()` can only handle objects built in R. I could be wrong about that, though.

Comment: From the documentation: `unserialize reads an object (as written by serialize) from connection or a raw vector.`

Comment: It seems to be difficulöt, c.f. http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/RData-File-Specification-td917010.html. Maybe somebody else has an idea ...

Comment: I know it's probably a hard ask, but if anyone understands the differences in the way Python objects and R objects are serialized and stored in memory then that might help me. The string I mentioned above can be decoded, parsed and read into memory in Python.

Comment: You could try a data format that both understand, e.g. https://blog.rstudio.com/2016/03/29/feather/

Comment: I can't deviate from XDR 4506, sadly.

Comment: This looks promising: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/R/pkg/R/serialize.R